# How to: MS Bot directline messaging using a websocket

Tags: javascript, botframework

I'm trying to figure out how to use MicroSoft bot Directline communication. I can connect fine, send and receive messages using POST and GET. My problem is when trying to use WebSockets. I start the conversation getting back my conversationId and streamUrl, I create a new WS using the streamUrl and am getting pinging by my bot periodically proving im connected. using we.Send() doesn't throw an error but I'm not getting a response. Does anyone know the next step? Thanks in advance.

```
function StartConversation(params) {
    fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations', {
            method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
            cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${BearerToken}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
            referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client 
        })
        .then(response => response.text())  
        .then(function (params) {
            localStorage.setItem(storageKey, params);
            ConnectWebSocet();
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(`Fetch Error =\n`, error));
}

function ConnectWebSocet() {
    var token = GetBotToken();
    ws = new WebSocket(token.streamUrl);
    ws.onopen = function (v, e) {
        console.log('open', v);
    };

    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
        console.log(evt);
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to get any response after sending message when using WebSockets (I could be wrong though). BTW, what are you expecting after sending message?

Comment: Hi @Meloy, any updates? Are you able to receive messages via WebSocket stream if you send some messages after you start a conversation?

Comment: Sorry, I’d moved on to a different strategy. I guess after sending another call is required to get new messages. I’m still new to this and am grateful for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> doesn't throw an error but I'm not getting a response.

Based on your code, we can find that you just [start a conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-start-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-3.0), but not [send activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). At that moment, perhaps no available messages could be pushed to client that connets via WebSocket, so you do not find any message is received and written to browser Console tab.

If you try to send an activity after you start a conversation, like below, your client that connects via WebSocket should be able to receive message(s).

***Send an activity and connect WebSocket after start conversation:***

```
//your code logic to start a conversation
.then(function (params) {
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, params);

    //send an activity to bot
    SendActivity();

    ConnectWebSocet();
})
```

***The definition of function `SendActivity()`:***

```
function SendActivity() {
    var token = GetBotToken();

    var mes = {
        "type": "message",
        "from": {
            "id": "Fei Han"
        },
        "text": "hello"
    };

    fetch(`https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/${token.conversationId}/activities`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${BearerToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(mes),
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(function (myJson) {
            console.log(myJson);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(`Fetch Error =\n`, error));
}
```

***Test result:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!